# Lagrangian saddle-point set is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a convex, continuously differentiable function. Let $\mathcal X \subset \mathbb R^n$ denote the set of solutions to the problem
$$ \min_{x \in \mathbb R^n} f(x) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad g(x) = 0, $$
where $g: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^p$ is a linear map with $p \leq n$. Assume that $\mathcal X$ is non-empty and compact.

Define $L: \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^p \rightarrow \mathbb R$ to be $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda^T g(x)$, and denote the set of min-max saddle points of $L$ by $$\mathcal S_L = \{(x^*, \lambda^*) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^p: \; L(x^*, \lambda) \leq L(x^*, \lambda^*) \leq L(x, \lambda^*) \; \forall (x, \lambda) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^p\}.$$ 
Under what condition(s) is $\mathcal S_{L}$ compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $g$ is linear, $g(x) = Ax$ for some $A$, and $Dg(x) = A$.

Note that $x \mapsto L(x, \lambda)$ is convex, hence $x'$ is a minimiser of
$x \mapsto L(x, \lambda)$ **iff** $Df(x')+\lambda^T A = 0$.

Note that if $n^T A  = 0$ then $L(x,\lambda) = L(x,\lambda+tn)$ for all $t$.

Suppose $(x^*,\lambda^*) \in S_L$, then since $L(x^*,\lambda) \le L(x^*,\lambda^*)$ 
for all $\lambda$ we must have $g(x^*) = 0$.

Since $f(x^*)=L(x^*,\lambda^*) \le L(x,\lambda^*)$ for all $x$, we see that if $g(x) = 0$ then $f(x^*) \le L(x,\lambda^*) = f(x)$
and so $x^* \in {\cal X}$.

We also see that $x^*$ is a minimiser of $x \mapsto L(x,\lambda^*)$ and so
$Df(x^*)+ {\lambda^*}^T A = 0$.

If $\ker A^T = \{0\}$ then we see that $\lambda^* = -(AA^T)^{-1}A Df(x^*)^T$, in particular, since $x \mapsto (x, -(AA^T)^{-1}ADf(x)^T)$ is continuous, we see that $S_L$ is compact since ${\cal X}$ is.

If $A^Tn = 0$ for some $n \neq 0$, we see that $(x^*,\lambda^*+tn) \in S_L$ for all $t$, hence $S_L$ is unbounded.

Comment: Is it necessarily true that $\ker A^T = 0$ implies $\lambda^* = -A(A^TA)^{-1}Df(x^*)^T$? Take, for example, $A = [1 \; -1] \in \mathbb R^2$. In this case, $\ker A^T = \{0\}$, where $0 \in \mathbb R$, and yet $A^TA$ is not invertible, so the above formula for $\lambda^*$ is undefined. Even so, it could still be the case that there exists a unique $\lambda^*$ for each $x^*$, as long as it satisfies $Df(x^*)+\lambda^{*T} A = 0$. How can we show compactness of $S_L$ in this case?

Comment: I just have the formula wrong, it is a standard left inverse, I mistakenly used the right inverse. $\ker A^T = \ker AA^T$, so $A A^T$ is invertible.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you write $g(x) = A \, x + b $, the matrix $A$ should have full rank. This condition is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not clear to me that this is true when $p < n$.